# php regex syntax to whitelist alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex, whitelist

I am trying to use preg_match to whitelist usernames with alphanumeric characters and screen out those with special characters but code is not acting as I'd like

Here is is:

```
PHP

$username = "karl#";
if (!preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$#", $username))
{
$msg = "You may not use special characters in your username";
}
else {
$msg = "ok";
}
```

returns "ok".  In other words, it is letting karl# get through.  I would like it to return error message.

Am I misusing preg-match or what am I doing wrong?  Thank you for any suggestions.

Edit: The code above does work.  Error was because in original version I was not hard coding the username but rather getting it as post and there was a problem with post.  I accepted the answer below using ^\w+$ as it allows for underscore and is more concise.  Thanks also for all the fine points on regex contained in comments.

Comment: I get the error message when I try it.

Comment: Error msg shows up for me as well..

Comment: Please post the actual code that experiences the problem. What you've posted should work fine.

Comment: Jeff and Joel where are you?   http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^\w+$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/yT2fZ5/1)**

As Barmar pointed in the comment this will allow underscores too, but if you don't want them then your regex is fine:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

You need to help the regex with the flags:

```
$re = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/m"; 
$username = "karl#";   ^----Notice the multiline flag
```

You also could use:

```
$re = "/^[a-z0-9]+$/mi"; 
                     ^---- Case Insensitive flag
```

Comment: That will allow underscores in addition to alphanumerics.

Comment: @Barmar good eye man, thanks for point that. Just mentioned it

Comment: OK, so now all you've done is abbreviate `0-9` as `\d`, saving a single character. While this might be stylistically better, why do you think it will solve his problem? His original code also works for everyone else. Whatever his problem is, it's not in the code in the question.

Comment: @Barmar The key on the regex is the `m` (multiline) flag

Comment: Why is that necessary? The input is just a single line.

Comment: BTW, why not add the `i` flag so you don't have to say both `a-z` and `A-Z`?

Comment: @Barmar in you enter in the link on my answer you can check the multiline flag comments, it says `Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string` so php may have some troubles reaching end of line instead end of string, this is like a help to regex engine

Comment: Your answer will say `OK` for `$username = "karl\nfred";`

Comment: @Barmar that's valid too, btw helpful too. I'll add that. Thanks, you rock

Comment: @Barmar no, it won't match "karl\nfred", check it here http://regex101.com/r/yT2fZ5/3

Comment: See http://ideone.com/rT5HWi

Comment: It matches `"karl\nfred"` because the `m` flag allows `$` to match before the newline, instead of matching just the end of the string.

Comment: Take the `g` flag out of your regex101 example and you'll see that it still matches.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with regex101. It highlighted `karl` on the third line, which means that the input matched.

Comment: I didn't mean a literal `\n` like you have on the first line, I meant a newline character, which is what you get if you put the `\n` escape sequence in a PHP double-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

Modified according to comments, I added delimiters for the pattern:

WORKING VERSION

```
<?php
$username = "karl";
if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", $username))
{
$msg = "You may not use special characters in your username";
}
else {
$msg = "ok";
}

echo $msg;
?>
```

place the not character within the range brackets.

Comment: `^` is not being used as a `not` character, it's being used as the `beginning-of-line` anchor.

Comment: 1. The expression is invalid. 2. You have a double negation.

Comment: @Barmar `^` within a character mask inverts it.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Why is the expression invalid?

Comment: @Barmar Because PHP requires you to have start- and end-delimiters. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: @Cobra_Fast, I added delimiters, and tested it, it works fine now.

Comment: @Charles Why do you think this will solve the OP's problem, since his original code also works.

Comment: @Barmar, the Ops code doesn't work, as it is letting illegal characters through like #,_ and so on. With this code, if the string is "hash#", then the if statement executes the first block stating that the character is illegal, else it says it's an Ok character.

Comment: How does the OP's code allow `#` through? It doesn't allow it through when I try it.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, I see what you are saying, I just tested the OPs code and it works. Guess I just read what the OP wrote saying it doesn't work,lol. My bad, or is it the OPs bad? We'll all share the blame :-)